# Xcode iPhone: Property ... requires method ... to be defined - use @syntehsize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

in an .m file I have 4 warnings relating to one command:

@end

- Property 'myHeader' requires method '-myHeader' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation
- Property 'customCell' requires the method 'setCustomCell:' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation
- Property 'customCell' requires method '-customCell' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation
- Property 'myHeader' requires the method 'setMyHeader' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation

I browsed through forums but I am hopeless so far - can you explain to me (beginner programmer...) how to debug it? Thanks a million!

Comment: The warnings tell you exactly what to do. Use the `@synthesize` or `@dynamic` directives, or provide your own implementations for those properties. If you're not sure what the means, you could always look up `@synthesize` and/or `@dynamic` in the documentation, or read about properties (since the warnings obviously pertain to properties that you've declared). I understand that it all seems daunting when you're a beginner, but the big step from beginner to not-so-beginner is learning to use the documentation.

Comment: It's fairly clear from your question that you are lacking in programming fundamentals. I would suggest picking up a book on Objective-C, such as Programming in Objective-C by Stephen Kochan: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Objective-C-3rd-Developers-Library/dp/0321711394/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1314130278&sr=8-1

Comment: glorifiedHacker, thanks for your input! I'm afraid I do not have the foggiest idea about programming... is the book you suggested appropriate for somebody like me (brave enough to attack Xcode and mess a bit in the code, actually with the sole intention of substituting the content [text and images])?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means that you need to synthesize those variables.  Synthesizing creates the setter and getter methods for you.  To do this, you need to include the following code in your implementation (.m) file:

```
@synthesize myHeader;
@synthesize customCell;
```

Adding these lines should take care of your 4 errors.

You also have the option of defining the setter and getter methods yourself, but unless you want to do something specific, go with @synthesize for now.

Answer (score 16):

Resuscitating an old thread.  Probably not the OP issue, but I thought it would be worth mentioning this, in case anyone else (like me) runs into this. You get the same message if you're implementing a new property in a class category (even puzzling if you're using LLVM 4 which no longer requires @synthesize).  This is possible using the technique outlined [here](http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/iphone-development/how-to-add-a-property-via-class-category/):

```
@interface SomeClass (Private)
@property (nonatomic, assign) id newProperty;
@end
NSString * const kNewPropertyKey = @"kNewPropertyKey";
@implementation SomeClass (Private)
@dynamic newProperty;
- (void)setNewProperty:(id)aObject
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kNewPropertyKey, aObject, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}
- (id)newProperty
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kNewPropertyKey);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 9):

In your class header (the associated .h file), you apparently have something resembling the following:

```
@property SomeClass *myHeader;
@property SomeClass *customCell;
```

This tells the compiler that you want your class to have these properties, but you still have to tell it how to get and set the values on instances. You have three options:

1. In the @implementation section (in the .m file), you can add

   ```
   @synthesize myHeader, customCell;
   ```

   to tell the compiler to automatically generate methods to get and set these properties. This is the easiest and usually what you want.
2. You can implement the methods yourself like so:

   ```
   - (SomeClass *)myHeader
   {
       // Return the value of myHeader
   }

   - (void)setMyHeader:(SomeClass *)inMyHeader
   {
       // Set myHeader to inMyHeader
   }
   ```

   This is generally used for derived or dynamically generated properties, or when you want to do extra work when they're changed.
3. You can use `@dynamic myHeader, customCell;` to tell the compiler that implementations will be provided at runtime. This is rarely used.

Comment: What if I have a class variable (which I'm using to check against an instance variable to see if its the same collection view cell that in reuse which is selected by user)?

Comment: Note: Both values are scalars. @ property (class) int selectedItemNumber;
@ property int reusedCellItemNumber;

Answer (score 3):

Using `@property` tells the compiler that you intend to access the corresponding member variable through "setter" and "getter" functions, i.e. functions which change the value of the variable or return its value.  The warnings you're seeing are because you have not defined the required functions.  I'm guessing your header (.h) file looks something like this:

```
@property(readwrite, assign) <type> myHeader;
@property(readwrite, assign) <type> customCell;
```

Because you've told the compiler that those variables should be accessible through setter and getter functions, you need to define those functions.  There are two ways of doing this.  The easiest is to use `@synthesize`, by adding the following to your implementation (.m) file:

```
@synthesize myHeader;
@synthesize customCell;
```

The `@synthesize` line causes the `- myHeader`, `- setMyHeader`, `- customCell` and `- setCustomCell` methods to be generated automatically at compile time.  You may also define those methods manually, but doing so is usually unnecessary.

[Here's a page with more information about properties in Objective C](http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/103).

Comment: @Artur: Thanks, good to know it helped.  You can click the check mark beside this answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ivars defined in @property statements, but you're missing the matching @synthesize statement.  Add the @synthesize to the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared an @property — this is effectively a contract saying you will implement getter and setter methods, but **you haven't.** You either need to:

- implement `-foo` and `-setFoo:` for each property, or
- use @synthesize in your `.m` file and the compiler will do it for you.

More info can be found in the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

You have some options, but the simplest, and probably what you want, is to use @synthesize.

In your .m file, somewhere after @implementation, add

```
@synthesize myHeader;
```

and likewise for the other properties.

In order for that to work, your class also has to have a member variable called myHeader. You might already have that. If not, in your .h file, somewhere after @interface, put

```
SomeType *myHeader;
```

Of course change "SomeType" to the appropriate type that's the same as you have in your property declaration (the thing you have that looks like)

```
@property (retain) SomeType *myHeader;
```